# Access pipeline failure stage info with Azure Devops via REST API or CLI

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to get information about which stages have failed during a pipeline failure using the Azure Devops REST API or CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using YAML pipeline, you can call [Builds-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api first:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.1
```

In `"_links"` you will find `timeline`:

```
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proId}/_apis/build/Builds/2703"
        },
        "web": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proId}/_build/results?buildId=2703"
        },
        "sourceVersionDisplayUri": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proId}/_apis/build/builds/2703/sources"
        },
        "timeline": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proId}/_apis/build/builds/2703/Timeline"
        },
        "badge": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proId}/_apis/build/status/29"
        }
    },
```

You will get the result of stages from `timeline`:

```
         {
            "previousAttempts": [],
            "id": "d4a9a205-d52e-57fb-7b17-15a9d984af62",
            "parentId": null,
            "type": "Stage",
            "name": "deploy",
            "startTime": "2020-03-23T08:42:37.2133333Z",
            "finishTime": "2020-03-23T08:42:46.9933333Z",
            "currentOperation": null,
            "percentComplete": null,
            "state": "completed",
            "result": "succeeded",
            "resultCode": null,
            "changeId": 7,
            "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "workerName": null,
            "order": 1,
            "details": null,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "warningCount": 0,
            "url": null,
            "log": null,
            "task": null,
            "attempt": 1,
            "identifier": "deploy"
        },
```

If you want to get the stage status in a release pipeline, you need to use [Get Release Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Timelines are exactly what I was looking for!